# Fill area between two non-linear curves without separation line in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to fill the area between two non-linear curves with some color, say "grey". There should not be any separation line within the shaded region. Also, the shaded region should be within the limit of the lower and upper bounds.

I have tried with the `fill_between` function, but as you can see in the figure, it has an extra line in it, and extends above the upper bound.

[image: Fill area between curve]

Could anyone help me to fix this problem? I have tried like:

```
plt.fill_betweenx(Y_upper, X_upper, X_lower, color='grey', alpha = 0.2)
plt.fill_between(X_lower, Y_upper, Y_lower, color='grey', alpha = 0.2)
```

Where `X_lower` and `Y_lower` represent the lower curve (curve in orange) and `X_upper` and `Y_upper` show the upper curve (green curve).

Comment: Hey @MeghalShah. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `fill_between(x, y1, y2)` to work, both `y1` and `y2` need to be calculated over the same x-range.  You could create a new array of x-values containing the x-values of both curves, in sorted order. And then use `np.interp` to recalculate the y-values of both curves.

Easier is to concatenate the reverse of the second curve to the first, which would create a closed polygon. `plt.fill` can than color that polygon.

The strange bump you see, are the y-values of the upper curve combined by the x-values of the shorter lower curve.

Here is an example to illustrate the idea:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_upper = np.linspace(-330, 40, 200)
y_upper = (40 - x_upper) * (x_upper + 330)
x_lower = np.linspace(-220, 20, 200)
y_lower = (20 - x_lower) * (x_lower + 220)
plt.plot(x_upper, y_upper, color='darkgreen')
plt.plot(x_lower, y_lower, color='orange')
plt.fill(np.append(x_upper, x_lower[::-1]), np.append(y_upper, y_lower[::-1]), color='black', alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(x_lower, y_upper, color='navy', ls='--', lw=0.5) # this is the strange curve seen 
plt.show()
```

[image: filling between two independent curves]